# Install ng2-translate library in Ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to install ng2-translate in my ionic 2 app using the [official doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/ng2-translate/). But it doesn't work. I don't understand why the official instructions don't work.

I get errors I don't understand, since I am a beginner.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { WeightlevelPage } from '../pages/weightlevel/weightlevel';
import { RecovolPage } from '../pages/recovol/recovol';
import { ComparePage } from '../pages/compare/compare';


export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json');
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    WeightlevelPage,
    RecovolPage,
    ComparePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    TranslateModule.forRoot(
      {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    )
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    WeightlevelPage,
    RecovolPage,
    ComparePage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I get those errors:

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'TranslateStaticLoader'.
src/app/app.module.ts
```

for this line `return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json')` and

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'TranslateLoader'.
src/app/app.module.ts
```

for this line: `provide: TranslateLoader,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `TranslateLoader` here :

> import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

And for the `createTranslateLoader`, make sure that these two folders `assets/i18n` are under `src`.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, it needs some polish.